# Where to buy glass to replace the broken glass part of my door?

Tags: glass

My entrance door has glasses. I'm in need of replacing the glass part of the door.
I need to know where to buy glasses?

Comment: In the US, I'd tell you to look in your phone book under "glass" -- there are stores which specialize in cut-to-order glass panes.

Comment: If you don't know how to anyway, just call a [glazier](https://www.google.com/search?q=glazier&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=glaziers+near+me).

Comment: See the [meta discussion](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/607/2196) for more details on our "shopping" policy.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are on Stack Exchange, I can safely assume you have access to the internet.  Use Google to search for 'Glass Store', and in its local search it should find some in your area.  If it doesn't, go to any hardware store and ask if they can order glass or cut glass to fit.  If they don't, ask them where you can go.

Comment: if you can, you should measure the thickness of the glass so you can tell them what to use to match the original piece. It should probably also be tempered if it's on a door.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that a glass shop can help you, but be sure to let them know it's for a door.  Building codes require better glass in doors, and even nearby windows.  I don't recall if the right term is "safety", or "tempered", or what.  The number of *kinds* of stronger, safer glass is rather surprising, so the glass experts can tell you what's right.

Comment: It's *tempered*, although tempered glass is a type of 'safety' glass. Laminated glass is primarily used in windshields. Tempered is required in various places, including doors, in a building, and does two things: won't break as easily, and when it does, breaks into round-edged pieces so it won't cut as easily.